# IIS cannot INSERT into SQL SERVER

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis, permissions

I have a web application that runs perfectly on my local computer. I published the website and I face a weird problem. When the user clicks a button on web, it should insert a row to a table. I can see the INSERT statement on SQL SERVER PROFILER, but it doesnt insert it. I took the INSERT STATEMENT on PROFILER and ran it on Management Studio, it inserts correctly. So INSERT statement is correct, I can send the INSERT statement correctly to SQL SERVER because I can see it on Profiler. But why it doesnt insert it from the website?

Also I realized that when the web sends the INSERT statement, PROFILER says that it spent 0 milisecond, but when I run the INSERT statement on Management Studio, I can see that it takes 35 miliseconds. Therefore, I thought IIS doesnt have right permission

what do you guys think? Any clue? I hope I made it clear

Comment: where do you think we should give the permissions? Should we do it on IIS or SQL SERVER? By the way, we are using the "sa" sql user to do jobs. I can do SELECT statements with "sa" user and it works perfectly @MitchWheat

Comment: The IIS user needs appropriate permissions in your database...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your connection string to SQL server and see authentication. I guess in your local (development) server you are using "integrated" auth or "sa" account.

Create new user on SQL Server (SQL auth. with username/password), give that user necessary permission on your database and set username/password in connection string accordingly.

Comment: And please don't use "sa" account. It's recommended to avoid usage of "sa" account. Set a strong password on that account, store that password on safe place and "forget" about it.